# Profile being imported even if the OU containing the user is excluded

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, fim

We are exluding a given OU from the profile import (OU=OLD):
[image]

However, a user belonging to that OU still shows up in the people picker:
[image]

Since the implementation of SharePoint here is really recent, I don't think that this user ever logged into SharePoint and created anything in there.

Does anyone has an idea about where it could come from?
Could it be related to the fact that this account still belongs to one group that is probably imported?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should check the proeprties of the user,and check if it part of different OU or groups which is on Import path.

Comment: Are you using AD Import or FIM?

Answer (score 2):

The `SharePoint Active Directory Import` does not mark the profile to be deleted either with incremental or Full Import when they are not selected and only way to remove the obsolete users is here.

You can follow below mentioned steps to solve your issue.

1. Run Full Import
2. Post that run Use SharePoint Management Shell to Run following

**Management Shell Commands**

```
$upa = Get-SPServiceApplication -id <Identity of User Profile Service Application>

Set-SPProfileServiceApplication -Identity $upa – PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

Comment: Thanks for the way to purge those old accounts. However, I wonder how the account got imported in the first place.

Comment: For that i need to look into your server... :)

Comment: I guess that won't be possible. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: ok but if your problem is resolved than please mark the answer. So other can get the help from it. Thanks

Comment: If you are using FIM the answer will be in the logs for the Import Connection.

Comment: I have carried out some experiment about this "container selection" interface before. I selected all containers, then unselect some containers, and save again. I found the "unselect" is not properly carry out. Some nodes (the user, not container) in lower level are still being sync according to the FIM log. The GUI have bug. I advice always delete the connection and build again.